# Undefined control sequence \babeltags

Tags: texlive, babel

I'm a beginner with LaTeX but I couldn't find anything on this problem:

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size

\usepackage[german, french, english]{babel} % multi-language support
\selectlanguage{english}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % for unicode input characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\babeltags{de = german, fr = french}
\textbf{Hello \textde{Hallo}}

\end{document}
```

I installed all language packages necessary.
I then tried this using TexMaker along with TexLive and directly from the command-line and I'm always getting 'Undefined control sequence \babeltags'.

So I'm guessing that somehow babel is not loaded correctly, but it should be included with TexLive. So what could be wrong here ?

EDIT: to be more precise, `selectlanguage{*}` is working for me, but I would like to make my document multilingual as suggested [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Multilingual_versions). So for that, I really need a shortcut for switching between languages.

Comment: That's a rather new command in babel, so is your system up-to-date?

Comment: that's a good suggestion, I didn't think this was a new feature. I just used the TexLive version coming with Ubuntu so that could be outdated. I'll update it and check again

Comment: You don't need `\selectlanguage{english}`. The last language specified is selected by default. Better to specify the variant of English you want e.g. `american` or `british` or whatever.

Comment: The reason this is in there is because I would like to switch the default language from one place in the end. Just like described in the wikibooks article, I would like to have a single source document from which I can compile different language versions in order to have all formatting in a single place

Comment: You seem to have an outdated version of `babel`. What TeX distribution and OS are you running?

Comment: Xubuntu 14.04 with the TexLive version from APT. I'm not surprised if that's not the latest version, so I'm currently downloading the newest version of TexLive. It'll take a while, but I'll report back after the upgrade. Thanks so far :)

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed an issue of version of babel, it is working fine with the new version of TexLive+babel. If you want to answer the question, I'll mark it as such

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you answer?

Answer (score 3):

`\babeltags`is a rather new command in babel. Make sure that your system is up-to-date.